# Compare or match 2 strings and display matched word

Tags: python-2.7

I would like to compare 2 strings and display any matched words.

For example -

string1 = "cat feet"
string2 = "cat shoes"

The result should = "cat"

How can I do this with regular expressions? Or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Split](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) each string on whitespace, and convert both to [sets](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset). Their [intersection](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set.intersection) will contain all of the words they have in common.

```
>>> set("cat feet".split()).intersection(set("cat shoes".split()))
set(['cat'])
```

This method does not care about ordering of words. "feet cat" and "cat shoes" will have output "cat", even though "cat" does not appear in the same position in both strings. If you want to find words that exist in the same position in both strings, you can [zip](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) the split strings together, and display only the words that exist in the same place in both:

```
>>> [a for a,b in zip("cat feet".split(), "cat shoes".split()) if a == b]
['cat']
>>> [a for a,b in zip("feet cat".split(), "cat shoes".split()) if a == b]
[]
```

Comment: Shows the expressive power of python.

Comment: That's great! Just to stretch this further, how would you match 2 words in each string and keep them in the correct order? 

e.g. 

"cat like feet" 
"cat like shoes" 

getting the result - "cat like"

set is not going to keep that order is it?

Comment: That depends. What is the correct order for the output of "cat like feet" matched with "like cat shoes", and why?

Comment: The correct order of the output should be "cat like" with the 2 strings being "cat like feet" and "cat like shoes". Why, as I would like to keep the matched words in the order they are written in the strings. Hope that makes sense! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Just regarding the use of regular expressions:
Regular expressions are equivalent to finite automatons and these have the property that they have only a finite set of states, which in turn means they have kind of finite memory. Thus you can't do stuff involving an unknown arbitrary lenght objective string.